# How do I keep just my iCloud contacts?

Tags: contacts

The Contacts app on my Mac has separate "On My Mac" and "iCloud" groups, but I really just want one set of contacts on iCloud that will be accessible on both my Mac and my phone.

Is there a way to merge the two sets of contacts and/or disable the "On My Mac" group?

Answer (score 1):

With Mavericks (OSX 10.9) once iCloud syncing activated you will not have the top level "On My Mac" anymore.

On earlier version best would be to :

1. Select every contact "**On My Mac**" (cmd - A) and drag and drop them
   to your "**~/Desktop**". This will create one VCF. To keep you group
   organisation you may want to proceed on a per group basis.
2. Delete the selection of contacts.
3. Delete the group(s).
4. Make sure in Contacts Preferences the default account is "**iCloud**". If you are
   missing contacts on iCloud simply drag and drop back the VCF file to
   "**All iCloud**" or whatever group, you will be prompted to review
   duplicates.

Comment: Is there some special trick to activate iCloud syncing? I have Mavericks, am logged into iCloud, but I still see distinct "iCloud" and "On My Mac" groups in Contacts

Comment: This means that iCloud Contacts is enabled. Do you have any contacts inside the "On My Mac group" when you click on it ? If so you should remove them, if not make sure the default account selected is iCloud.